# Android layout issues

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I can't for the life of me figure this out.  I am attempting to have the following layout (vertically):

ImageView (filling all available space)
TextView (taking vertical space as needed)
EditText (taking vertical space as needed)
Button Button Button (spaced equally)

I have the following layout setup.  The image view is currently set at 200dip.  What should this value be to fill all available space?  The other components should come first and the image view should get what's left over.  I have searched for an example on this and have not found anything yet.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgView"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="200dip"              
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

   <TextView android:id="@+id/lblDesc"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/PhotoDesc"             
             android:layout_below="@id/imgView" />

   <EditText android:id="@+id/edtDesc"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"                         
             android:layout_below="@id/lblDesc" />

   <!-- Bottom layout contains the three buttons - Take Photos, Transmit, and Setup. -->
   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:weightSum="3">

      <!-- Take photos button -->
      <Button android:id="@+id/btnCamera"
              android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"              
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"              
              android:text="@string/TakePhotos" />

      <!-- Transmit button -->
      <Button android:id="@+id/btnUpload" 
              android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"              
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"              
              android:text="@string/Upload" />              

      <!-- Setup button -->
      <Button android:id="@+id/btnSetup"
              android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"              
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/Setup"              
              android:layout_weight="1" />
   </LinearLayout>                    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like all you need is a `LinearLayout` with appropriate weight on the `ImageView` to take the leftover space.

layout_weight with `LinearLayout` is often misunderstood. `LinearLayout` measures its children in two passes. First, children are measured based on the given layout_width or layout_height, then after all children have been measured any extra space left over is divided according to their weights.

This means two important things:

- You never want to say match_parent (or fill_parent on older versions) with a weight in the direction of the layout. (i.e. `layout_width="match_parent"` for a `LinearLayout` with `orientation="horizontal"` or `layout_height="match_parent"` for `orientation="vertical"`.) match_parent will take effect first, consuming all currently available space and leaving none left over for the remaining children.
- When you want to divide space equally between several views with weight or have one view consume whatever space is left without regard to the actual content size, use 0dip as the `layout_width` or `layout_height` value.

Try this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgView"
          android:layout_width="match_parent" 
          android:layout_height="0dip"              
          android:layout_weight="1" />

   <TextView android:id="@+id/lblDesc"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/PhotoDesc"             
         android:layout_below="@id/imgView" />

   <EditText android:id="@+id/edtDesc"
         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"                         
         android:layout_below="@id/lblDesc" />

   <!-- Bottom layout contains the three buttons - Take Photos, Transmit, and Setup. -->
   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:weightSum="3">

      <!-- Take photos button -->
      <Button android:id="@+id/btnCamera"
          android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
          android:layout_width="0dip"              
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"              
          android:text="@string/TakePhotos" />

      <!-- Transmit button -->
      <Button android:id="@+id/btnUpload" 
          android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
          android:layout_width="0dip"              
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"              
          android:text="@string/Upload" />              

      <!-- Setup button -->
      <Button android:id="@+id/btnSetup"
          android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"              
          android:layout_width="0dip"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/Setup"              
          android:layout_weight="1" />
   </LinearLayout>                    

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Awesome, two answers at once!  Both are correct, but the simple explanation about how the layout spacing is divided was extremely helpful.  I'm on day 2 of Android development and I just wasn't getting it!  Thanks!

Comment: I didn't want to clutter the answer with two many extra details, but since you liked the extra info, here's another interesting tip. If you use the 0dip/weight technique with a child of a LinearLayout it skips the initial measure pass for that child and only relies on the weight measurement pass. (Children without weight only rely on one pass as well.) This can be a significant optimization if that child is actually a complex sub-hierarchy that takes some time to measure.

Answer (score 3):

Change your `RelativeLayout` to a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"`, then add `android:layout_weight="1"` to your ImageView.

Example code below. I set the background of the ImageView to the color red to see the effect.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:orientation="vertical">

   <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgView"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="0dp"              
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:background="#FF0000" />

   <TextView android:id="@+id/lblDesc"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="test" />

   <EditText android:id="@+id/edtDesc"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <!-- Bottom layout contains the three buttons - Take Photos, Transmit, and Setup. -->
   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:weightSum="3">

      <!-- Take photos button -->
      <Button android:id="@+id/btnCamera"
              android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"              
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"              
              android:text="btn1" />

      <!-- Transmit button -->
      <Button android:id="@+id/btnUpload" 
              android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"              
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"              
              android:text="btn2" />              

      <!-- Setup button -->
      <Button android:id="@+id/btnSetup"
              android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"              
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="btn3"              
              android:layout_weight="1" />
   </LinearLayout>                    

</LinearLayout>
```