# How to add another button or a textview right next to another button?

Tags: android, xml, layout, button, android-linearlayout

How can i add another button or textview right next the another button? I'm new in Android programming and XML as well
Here is my xml code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:background="@drawable/background_start"
     >

 <Button 

         android:id="@+id/prvo"
         android:text="Прво копче" 
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:layout_marginTop="25px"
         android:layout_margin="15px"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:visibility="visible"

         android:onClick="hello"
         />
 <EditText android:maxLines="1" 
 android:scrollbars="vertical" 
 android:text="Пиши нешто овде" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 

 android:id="@+id/editText1" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Should i change the layout template? Switchit to relative or table layout instead of linear?

Comment: Doesn't the above work? Try adding 'android:weight="1"' to Button and EditText if they dont appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
    android:text="Blah" 
    android:id="@+id/addemail" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
</Button>
<Button
    android:text="Blergh" 
    android:id="@+id/sendmail" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" >
 </Button>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130618/android-layout-issues/5130694#5130694) its pretty good.

Comment: Can i do this with nesting the buttons in the layout <Buttons *some preferences for the first button* then /> <Button *some preferences for the 2nd button* then /></Button></Button>

Comment: @NikolaMKD edited my answer with what you want. Also the xml in your comment is not quite right.